# Anti Proxy Debugging WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, proxy

I know of a WPF application that whenever I try and open any Proxy debugging tool, e.g. [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), [Proxyman.io](https://proxyman.io/) etc... I get this:

[image: this]

Does anyone know how I can recreate this in my WPF application. Is there a 3rd party app or a nuget that can do this. I know that I can constantly be looking for a file with those names, but someone could either rename the Applications or use another which I do not know about.

Comment: So, you want to detect whether or not a proxy is enabled?

Comment: Yes. So if the user opens a debugging proxy, it will shut down the application

Comment: I think its in the system paramater somewhere. Try ti search on proxy settings in C#, surely yhere must be something availabe

Comment: It's more tricky than I thought. When does the popup comes? Directly after starting the proxy? If so, the must be some eventhandler invoked.

Comment: If you have a copy of this app, you could try a decompiler like reflector and search for that string. See how they did it. Btw. You know lots of businesses have internal proxy servers?

Comment: @Stefan the popup pops up whenever I open up a debugging proxy, no matter what state the app is in, it pops the message and immediately shuts the application. Andy, the application is obfuscated using DNGuard which is a pain and almost impossible to deobfuscate manually and the one unpacker for it was only for 32bit systems so unfortunately, I was unable to run it. To answer your second question, I am quite aware of businesses having internal proxy servers but I want to know if there is a way to do it in C# or at least a way to know whether someone is proxy debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I did find a semi-solution. My overall goal was to stop people doing a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) with programs such as Fiddler and Charles which can decrypt HTTPS **IF** you accept their certificate on your device. I was able to achieve this using SSL Pinning, using the Public Key for the specific site certificate I wanted and comparing to whether it matches the one I have stored beforehand and during runtime. I won't post any code, as it can be found in a series of different StackOverflow questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777017/c-sharp-net-pinning-certificates-authorities-i-am-doing-it-correctly) and as it does not directly answer my original question found above. Although, I hope that **this** method does help some of you wondering how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to define a Design Mode and create an exception or change other behavior.
See the DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode Method in [Is there a DesignMode property in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425760/is-there-a-designmode-property-in-wpf).

Comment: How does this relate to detecting a proxy?

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question.
Sorry.